# How rails component interact with each other in background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

For example: How objects are called from controller on view?
Which methods, techniques are running in background?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is like how components in airplane interact with each other so plane flies?
Anyway, when you call any action at any url, Rails will try to match it with routes.

```
get 'posts', to: "posts#index"
```

will match `/posts` routes and will look through your controllers and start `PostsController.action(:index)`.

After that, while executing `index` action of your controller it will initialize instance variable `@posts` which is usually `Post.all`.

And the last thing, `PostsController` will call renderer, passing action, all instance variables, sessions and url-params. `ActionView Renderer` will initialize the instance of view with proper template `app/views/posts/index.html.erb`, put variables there and send page to user.

Comment: Thanks Ivan!. Could you please tell me which methods are call when objects are interact with controllers??

Comment: well there are alot of them chaining, and under different patterns. Please take a look at episodes Brock mentioned for complete picture of what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

you should check these out

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/397-action-view-walkthrough
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/395-action-controller-walkthrough
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/319-rails-middleware-walkthrough

These screencasts will show you what happens in the background.